# ERD for website that sells machines and lets you download a mobile app that controls them

Tags: entity-relationship, erd

I'm creating an ERD for my graduation project creating a website that sells coffee machines and lets you download a mobile app that controls them remotely:

[image]

I will add the attributes and the relation for an entity "payment".

How can I improve this ERD?

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097) An ERD is an image of DDL. PS Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. 
Paraphrase or quote from other text with credit. PS Image and/or text: Give just what you need & relate it to your problem.

Comment: What is your 1 specific question? What does your research show that is relevant? What published DB design textbook/reference/presentation are you following? What design method? Where is the 1st place you are stuck/unsure? Why/how are you stuck/unsure? [ask] [Help] [mre] [research effort](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [“help me"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/3404097) [homework](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/334822/3404097) PS You give no specification details by which one could create or evaluate a design.

Comment: @philipxy There is no standardised DDL for representing an ERD.  Tables and columns in an SQL schema are not substitutes for entities relationships an attributes, and only represent one possible implementation of an ERD.

Comment: @Christophe It doesn't have to be any particular DDL, the text from the ERD & a simple statement of the presence of each line & shape is defacto DDL & gives the entire ERD design content entirely in text. "Images should only be used to illustrate problems that can't be made clear in any other way"

Comment: @philipxy the D of ERD stands for Diagram.  For questions on diagrams, images are the only way to accurately illustrate the problem.  Text alternatives are only approximations of what's in the diagram (N-N relationship betwenn diagram and text representation). In conclusion questions tagged ERD qualify for pictures. If you don't like diagrams you can simply ignore questions with this tag. You are very skilled in database and sql questions. There are plenty of them without ERD tag where I would fully support your point of view.

Comment: @Christophe "the D" That is irrelevant, ERD content is trivially given in text & see the FAQ. I am done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We cannot judge if the entities and relationships are correct, as we don't have the requirements.

However, it is already possible to suggest improvements:

- Add the cardinalities on each relationship.  For example has a `Website` only one `Coffee Machines` or several?  And is a `Coffee machine` had by only one `website` or can a same machine belong to several sites?  This is essential to understand the nature of the relationships but also to derive a database implementation.
- Two entities such as C`offee machine` and `Order` shall not be directly related: a relationship is missing in-between.
- Avoid relationship names such as "Has" as much as possible. Try to be more specific. For example `Website` *registers* `Membership` or `Customer` *orders* `Order` or `Website` proposes `Coffee machine`
- The relationship between the customer and the app and the app and the machine is not fully clear.  It raises more questions than it answers:  do you mean that you offer a catalogue of apps to download ?  Will your database contain the apps ?  Or do you just want to say that the customers can download an app from the website (no need to have  an entity for the latter case).